# Fetched object is not assigned to React state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, fetch-api

I am successfully fetching data on an object and I'm trying to assign it to state `movie`. However, when I console it out, it has value `undefined`.

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import Topbar from '../Header/Topbar';

const movieApiBaseUrl = "https://api.themoviedb.org/3";

interface Movie {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  rating: number;
  description: string;
  picture?: string;
  date: string;
}

const MoviePage = (props: any) => {

const [movie, setMovie] = useState<Movie>();

const currentMovieId = window.location.pathname.split('/')[2];


useEffect(() => {

  fetch(
    `${movieApiBaseUrl}/movie/${currentMovieId}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
  )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => setMovie(res.results))
    .catch(() => {
        return {};
    });


  console.log('movie ', movie); // HERE IT CONSOLES OUT undefined

}, [currentMovieId, movie]);


  return (
    <React.Fragment>
        <Topbar></Topbar>
        <div>
          Here fetched data will be displayed
        </div>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default MoviePage;
```

Do you know why?

Comment: Fetch requests are asynchronous. You’re logging it before the fetch has completed.

Comment: `fetch` is asynchronous. You're trying to log the value of state that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: check this video to better understand the async behaviour : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Comment: Thanks! However, when I try to use `{movie.title}` inside the component, I get an error `Object is possibly 'undefined'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

access it with a new effect to see the state update since state update is asynchronous

```js
useEffect(() => {

  fetch(
      `${movieApiBaseUrl}/movie/${currentMovieId}?api_key=${process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY}`
    )
    .then((res) => res.json())
    .then((res) => setMovie(res.results))
    .catch(() => {
      return {};
    });



}, [currentMovieId]);


//access it with a new effect to see the state update since state update is asynchronus
useEffect(() => {

  console.log("::Movie::", movie)


}, [movie]);
```

Comment: Thanks! This helped me to see that the state has default values (I have added default values to the state). I believe, fetched values are not assigned to the stated since fetched object has more properties than the state